# ERROR Permission denied (publickey, gssapi-keyex, gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: ssh, server, continuous-integration, vps, cd

this is my log for ssh -vvv root@107.173.2.141

[image: debug 1]
[image: debug2]
[image]

i've tried many method

1. AllowUsers
2. PasswordAuthentication Yes & PasswordAuthentication No
3. PAM Yes & PAM No

For sure there is my server spec

1. Centos 7
2. VPS Witho Virtualization
3. 1 Core 1 Gb of RAM
4. I'll make this for ci CD

Answer (score 0):

First, double-check that /root/.ssh/authorized_keys does have your public key in it (`/users/xxx/id_rsa.pub`)

Then, if it fails, try if possible on the server to [stop the SSH daemon](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-stop-start-restart-sshd-command/), and restart it in debug mode:  `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -D`: a manuel one-time session, which will print whatever query it receives.
That way, you will know why the destination refuses your SSH query.